# Which message should I handle if I need to detect a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say I am looking for the keyboard short-cut **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** in my application. I believe I must not handle `WM_KEYDOWN` for various reasons, one being that it is for detecting non-system keys and does not tell you about the **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** key specifically. It has only a 1-bit flat to tell you if *any* extended key was pressed along with the virtual key.

I believe `WM_CHAR` is a more appropriate one for me here. My questions are:

a) Am I right in my assumption?

b) How do I get the character code from `wParam` and compare it with, say, **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**?

Comment: are you writing a windows forms or wpf application? if so, is there a reason why you don't hook onto the KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress events?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I am writing a VSTO Office Add-in and hence the keyboard events are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WM_SYSKEYDOWN and WM_SYSCHAR to detect the Alt keypress.

You have more information in [this article](http://www.ngedit.com/a_wm_keydown_wm_char.html).

a) No, WM_CHAR won't detect and alt press.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a co-incidence, I was in the middle of that very article when I posted this question. Thanks much.

Comment: Just another question, for WM_SYSCHAR, how do I compare the character code in wParam with the character I am looking for, in this case, the character C? I am doing this in C#. If it was C or C++, it would have been a straight-forward comparison. Could you tell me if I need to compare the character code with the integer value of the virtual key?

Comment: I think you have to compare the integer code to see if it matches yhe ascii representation for that character.

Answer (score 0):

For general keyboard shortcut handling it'd better use `Control.ProcessCmdKey` override.

It is called as Keyboard Accelerators in Win32.

I don't have direct experience of `Control.ProcessCmdKey`but it looks like easy thing to do.

Example found by Google search:
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4639

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey( ref Message msg, 
                                       Keys keyData )
{
    // Check this key...
    bool bHandled = false;

    // Look up value
    Accelerators accel = Accelerators.Unspecified;
    if ( _accelHash.ContainsKey(AcceleratorKey(keyData)) )
    {
        accel = (Accelerators)_accelHash[key];

        switch ( accel )
        {
            case Accelerators.Home:
                DisplayHome();
                bHandled = true;
                break;

            case Accelerators.Save:
                Save();
                bHandled = true;
                break;

            case Accelerators.Print:
                Print();
                bHandled = true;
                break;

            case Accelerators.Logout:
                LogOut();
                bHandled = true;
                break;

            case Accelerators.Unspecified:
            default:
                break;

        } // switch
    } // if

    return bHandled;
}
```